# Convert array of NSStrings to array of formatted NSNumbers

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have an array of strings called `valuesArray` containing values like this: 2913451.0938

I am trying to format those numbers so that I can display them like this: 2,913,451.09

Using the following code I am able to read the values from the array and convert them to NSNumbers (`num`), and I am also able to create a formatter to define how I want my numbers to be displayed (`formatter`).

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSNumber *num = valuesArray[indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"num: %@",num);
NSLog(@"Formatter: %@",formatter);
NSString *forNum = [formatter stringFromNumber:num];
NSLog(@"FormattedNum: %@",forNum);
```

When I run the code and get to the line `NSLog(@"FormattedNum: %@",forNum);` I see that it prints `null`. What am I missing?

Comment: What do `num` and `formatter` print?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe `num: 12553726.204939000000000` , `Formatter: <NSNumberFormatter: 0x75bb820>` and `FormattedNum: (null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you retrieve an element from you array of strings `valueArray` but assign it to an `NSNumber` typed variable—while the object really is an `NSString`. When you pass it to the formatter it returns `nil` (even though it also might crash, it's just undefined behavior).

You have to convert the string to an `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumber *num = @([valuesArray[indexPath.row] doubleValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this code with this value :

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSNumber *num = @(2913451.0938);

NSLog(@"num: %@",num);
NSLog(@"Formatter: %@",formatter);
NSString *forNum = [formatter stringFromNumber:num];
NSLog(@"FormattedNum: %@",forNum);
```

**It worked fine, no error what so ever as you mentioned.**

See the Output :

```
2013-02-28 21:35:44.417 BrowserModal[4861:403] num: 2913451.0938
2013-02-28 21:35:44.418 BrowserModal[4861:403] Formatter: <NSNumberFormatter: 0x100160840>
2013-02-28 21:35:44.419 BrowserModal[4861:403] FormattedNum: 29,13,451.09
```

---

Please clean your target and re-build.

And

Make sure `valuesArray[indexPath.row]` returns a boxed `NSNumber` object.

Do as : @([valuesArray[indexPath.row] doubleValue]);

Comment: What do you mean by a boxed `NSNumber` object?

Comment: use `@([valuesArray[indexPath.row] doubleValue]);`

Comment: I missed to answer earlier than nikolai, I went for dinner then you asked your question, my badluck :(